# How to launch a java program from another java program?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have 2 java programs inside a package in a netbeans project. 1 is Run.java and the other is JdbcSqlServerConnectivity.java. I referred earlier questions on this topic, but none of the solutions seems to be working. I get following errors

```
javac JdbcSqlServerConnectivity.java stderr: javac: file not found: JdbcSqlServerConnectivity.java
javac JdbcSqlServerConnectivity.java stderr: Usage: javac <options> <source files>
javac JdbcSqlServerConnectivity.java stderr: use -help for a list of possible options
javac JdbcSqlServerConnectivity.java exitValue() 2
java JdbcSqlServerConnectivity stderr: Error: Could not find or load main class JdbcSqlServerConnectivity
java JdbcSqlServerConnectivity exitValue() 1
```

Run.java code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Run {

  private static void printLines(String name, InputStream ins) throws Exception {
    String line;
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(ins));
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(name + " " + line);
    }
  }

  private static void runProcess(String command) throws Exception {
    Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/" + command + "");
    printLines(command + " stdout:", pro.getInputStream());
    printLines(command + " stderr:", pro.getErrorStream());
    pro.waitFor();
    System.out.println(command + " exitValue() " + pro.exitValue());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      runProcess("javac JdbcSqlServerConnectivity.java");
      runProcess("java JdbcSqlServerConnectivity");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to run `JdbcSqlServerConnectivity` in a separate process?

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the full system path of file `JdbcSqlServerConnectivity.java`. For instance if `JdbcSqlServerConnectivity.java` is located inside `D:\Temp\com\example` directory then you should specify as below:

```
runProcess("javac D:\\Temp\\com\\example\\JdbcSqlServerConnectivity.java");
runProcess("java D:\\Temp\\com\\example\\JdbcSqlServerConnectivity");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

runProcess("java -cp *fullpath* JdbcSqlServerConnectivity.java");